# Adding Framework based on iOS 5

Tags: ios, xcode, core-bluetooth

I have an app that provides bluetooth support. And the app has to support iOS 4.3 onwards. CoreBluetooth framework is unavailable in 4.3. Is it possible to exclude the library when the app is installed on iOS 4.3 device?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

YES you can set it as **optional** as shown in below image:

go to your LinkedFramworks and Binary section and chage it as optional[image]

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. It is possible. When you add library to your frameworks, just define it as `optional` in `projectsetting->Build Phases -> Link Binary with Libararies` -> CoreBluetooth.framework set as optional

Answer (score 0):

```
YES it is possible.You can make CoreBluetooth.framework  `Optional` in your `Link Binary With Libraries`.
```